# MySQL Insert and merge into new Table with Rows from one Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as follows:

```
id - rowid - value - date
```

and in each row I have:

```
1 - 9 - 123 - 03/2013
2 - 10 - 456 - 03/2013
```

I want to join both rows into one table like this:

```
id - rowid - value1 value2 - date
1 - 9 - 123 - 456 - 03/2013
```

I only need from the first table, the rowid 9 as in the example and the value and date.

From the second row I only need the value. I tried union all and multiple selection but with no success effort.

Help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the query you have tried..?

Comment: lots but last was this: INSERT INTO `tbl2`(`rowid`, `val1`, `val2`, `date`)
VALUES(
(SELECT `rowid` FROM `tbl1` WHERE `rowid`=9),
(SELECT `val1` FROM `tbl1` WHERE `rowid`=9),
(SELECT `date` FROM `tbl1` WHERE `rowid`=9),
(SELECT `val2` FROM `tbl1` WHERE `rowid`=10))

Comment: Are there always only two rows with the same date?

Comment: The rows in tbl1 are identical in terms of there sense - it consist of read and write data from disk io. now i want to merge both values into one tbl2. the date typ is datetime and therefor no line matches each other in any col. e.g. rowid 9 and rowid 10 are the same disk but follows with diffent values e.g. read write and time of it. hope it helps

Comment: Please edit all necessary info into the question.

Answer (score 0):

--Assumes there are ONLY 2 records in table with same date.
--If not accurate you will end up with only 1 less record per date than you currently have.
--Assumes you only what the lowest RowId recorded.

```
create table myNewtable as 
(SELECT A.RowID, A.Value, B.Value, A.Date
 FROM Oldtable A INNER JOIN Oldtable B 
  on A.Date=B.Date 
  and A.RowID < B.RowId)
```

--Now that we know date is date time and is likely different...
but that RowID is always +1 for the ones you want to join

```
create table myNewtable as 
(SELECT A.RowID, A.Value, B.Value, A.Date
 FROM Oldtable A 
 INNER JOIN Oldtable B 
  on A.RowID = B.RowId-1)
```

Comment: Ah ok i can also join with b.rowid-1. nice to know. but the table allready exists. can i use this for insert? i only have one oldtable, you descripted oldtableA and B, right?

Comment: Yep just alter the syntax so it's a insert into select instead of of a create table  (See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html) for example

Comment: i forgot, the oldtable tbl1 has further rows with rowid11 to 26 which i must merge on the same way but into dif. table.

Comment: oh ok i understand its an synonyme ;) ok will try later i deleted the testtabel and have to restore it - thx so far